# Magento 1.9: get data from text area in observer using event?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I need get data from text area in which customer write comment, than that comment I need add to order using sales_order_place_before event and save order to sales_flat_order. Customer comment must add to table with new column which I created, it's named 'comment'

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: I'm stuck, I can't get data from text area which located in checkout block, and than add this comment to order in sales_flet_order(to  my custom column 'comment').

Comment: Have you created Order Atrribute ?

Comment: no, can you tell me more about this Order Atrribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1 :** Create custom order attribute.
Create a custom module and create a Mysql installer file in your module. {/app/code/local/namespace/modulename/sql/module_setup/mysql4-install-1.1.php}.
Before this make sure you have added all resource model related information in etc/config.xml.

Put the content in the file.

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("order", "order_comment", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "order_comment", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->endSetup();
```

**Step 2 :** Create an Observer to save the details for event `checkout_type_onepage_save_order`.

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer 
{
    public function saveCustomData($event)
    {
        $quote = $event->getSession()->getQuote();
        $quote->setData('order_comment', $event->getRequestModel()->getPost('order_comment'));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** In your etc/config file make sure you write fiedset quote to order conversion code.

```
<global>
         <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>                           
                <order_comment><to_order>*</to_order></order_comment>
            </sales_convert_quote>

            <sales_convert_order>                                              
                <order_comment><to_quote>*</to_quote></order_comment>
            </sales_convert_order>
        </fieldsets>
</global>
```

For more reference on custom EAV Order attribute please refer http://ka.lpe.sh/2013/05/10/magento-add-attribute-to-order/

Hope it finds you helpful.
Thanks